# R how to pull data from internal web database to shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have built a few ShinyApps and am now running in to a new barrier. Specifically, I am having trouble pulling data from internal databases that are hosted at a URL. So far, I have been able to build a script to pull the data from a JSON file (getting the URL from Developer Tools in Firefox). After parsing and cleaning, I can get the desired information to 'renderPrint'. However, I am having trouble getting the reactive portion to work.

What I would like is for the user to select an input from a drop down box (e.g. 1-5) and have the user input be reactive, updating the GET request (httr). I have done this with other sites like wikipedia, however, this is done through reactive text. Is there  away to have the URL update with the input? What I currently have (note: this pulls the same base URL, regardless of input - however, if I change the number manually, I get the relevant page (e.g. =1 [pg.1], =2[pg.2]).

***Begin R Script***

```
url<-GET('https://somewebsite.com/results_json /11111?page=1),add_headers("user-agent"-'Firefox/60.0')) 

url_content<-content(web3)

url_summary<-list(url_content[[2]])

results-capture.output(url_summary %>% modify_depth(2,'hostName') %>% str())

results<-as.data.frame(results)

results(as.data.frame(gsub("[[:punct:]]","",as.matrix(results))

results<-as.character(results$results)

results<-as.data.frame(results,stringAsFactors=FALSE)
```

***END R Script***

As I said, this works just dandy, but I would like to have the userinput (dropdown list) update the URL. I have ran tests and the follow-on code works regardless of page number. However, just cannot get it to update...

***BEGIN ShinyApp***

```
ui<-pageWithSidebar(
  titlePanel("Data Pool"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputID="pg",
    label="page",
    choices=c("1"="1","2"="2","3"="3"),
    selected="1"),
  actionButton('submit','Submit')
),
mainPanel(
  verbatimTextOutput("data_ids")
) )

server<-(function(input,output) {
  observeEvent(input$submit,{
    x<-as.character(input$pg)
    url<-GET(paste0('https://somewebsite.com/results_json/11111?page=',x), add_headers("user-agent"="Firefox/60.0))})
```

## where 'x' is the user input (e.g. '1') and this updates the url to .../11111?page=1

```
#here I run the same code as I did in the RScript above#

results<-as.data.frame(gsub("chr","",as.matrix(results)))
results<-as.data.frame(results[-1])

  output$data_ids<-renderPrint({
    as.matrix(results)})
})

shinyApp(ur=ur,server=server)
```

***END APP**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following in the server

```
server<-function(input,output) {

  results <- reactive({
    x<-as.character(input$pg)
    address <- paste0('https://somewebsite.com/results_json/11111?page=',x)
    # url<-GET(address, add_headers("user-agent"="Firefox/60.0"))
    # results<-as.data.frame(gsub("chr","",as.matrix(results)))
    # results<-as.data.frame(results[-1])
    address
  })

  output$data_ids<-renderPrint({
    as.matrix(results())
  })
}
```

Note that the last line of `results`-reactive should be the thing you want to pass as the result. I didn't have a website address to test with, so I only print the address, that seems to be in the wanted form.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow! If you feel the answer solved the problem, you can also mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.